# Move a button to another tr programatically

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a login form designed using a `<table>` in an ASP.NET application.

[image]

A client is asking to modify the layout by moving around a few UI controls. They want to move the Forgot Password link below the Login button so they are on separate lines.

[image]

However, for all other clients, everything needs to remain the same, so if any CSS or style changes need to be done, I would need to do it programatically. Are there any easy ways to do this?

I am trying to avoid creating duplicate user controls to fit the layout they want, and then hide/show controls, depending on the client.

```
<table style="TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed; WIDTH: 370px;">
  <COLGROUP>
    <COL width="120px">
    <COL width="250px">
  </COLGROUP>
  <tr>
    <td>Username:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="password"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align:right;">
            <a href="url">Forgot Password</a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/wz7s0tee/2/)

**EDIT: jQuery NOT allowed. JavaScript OK.**

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to archive that.

Here is an example of moving the button one step back

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var loginLayOut = $(".login");    // login Table
    var btnTd = loginLayOut.find("button").parent(); // button container, in this case its td
    var tbody = btnTd.parent().parent();    // we get the tbody by moving two step back
    var tr = $("<tr></tr>");     // create a new tr
    tr.append(btnTd);            // append the td to the new created tr
    tbody.prepend(tr);           // insert the tr to the tbody at position 0
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='login' style="TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed; WIDTH: 370px;">
  <COLGROUP>
    <COL width="120px">
    <COL width="250px">
  </COLGROUP>
  <tr>
    <td>Username:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="password"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align:right;">
            <a href="url">Forgot Password</a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Any way other ways to achieve this as jQuery is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery can do this for you.  the code might look something like this:

```js
$("#toggle").click(toggleButtonPosition);

function toggleButtonPosition() {
  var buttonRow = $("button[type=submit]").closest("tr"), buttonCell, newTR, tr;

  if (buttonRow.find("td").length === 2) {
    // the table is in its initial configuration.  Need to extract the button cell and add it to a new row
    buttonCell = buttonRow.find("button").closest("td");
    buttonCell.remove();

    newTR = $("<tr />").append(buttonCell);

    newTR.insertBefore(buttonRow);
  } else {
    // Reverse the process
    buttonCell = buttonRow.find("td");

    tr = buttonRow.siblings().first();

    tr.append(buttonCell);

    buttonRow.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed; WIDTH: 370px;">
  <COLGROUP>
    <COL width="120px">
    <COL width="250px">
  </COLGROUP>
  <tr>
    <td>Username:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="password"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align:right;">
            <a href="url">Forgot Password</a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggle">Toggle Button Position</a>
```

Comment: Any way other ways to achieve this as jQuery is not allowed.

Comment: yes.. technically, all jquery is is a ton of javascript packaged up into plugins... but it wouldn't be easy at all.  In that case, i would recommend what one of the answers was... just have to forgot password links, and show/hide them as needed.  You can do that just with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to duplicate the layout. You can do it by adding/ removing the css class depending upon the client using jquery or javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var client1 = true; // variable to store client
 if(client1){
  $('button').removeClass('client2').addClass('client1');
 } 
else {
 $('button').removeClass('client1').addClass('client2');
 }});
```

Css classes to be added/removed from the button depending upon the client. I have put 'client1' css class on the button.

```
button.client1{display:block;margin:0 auto}
button.client2{float:right;margin-left:4px}
```

Html code as follows:

```
<table style="TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed; WIDTH: 370px;">
 <COLGROUP>
  <COL width="120px">
  <COL width="250px">
 </COLGROUP>
 <tr>
  <td>Username:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Password:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="password"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>
   <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button type="submit" class='client1'>Login</button>
         <a href="url">Forgot Password</a>            
      </td>         
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I can't seem to make this work with just adding the CSS alone. Am I missing something? https://jsfiddle.net/wz7s0tee/4/

Comment: Yes, you need to add the jquery script that I posted above, to see the change depending upon the client. In that script if you set var client1 value to false, you will see the second layout

Comment: I think the CSS is not working. I tried assigning client1 and client2 classes to the button, and neither seem to have the desired affect. The jQuery code simply swaps the classes, but the CSS is the part that doesn't seem to be working, regardless of which CSS class I use.

Comment: With the jQuery, still not working even when I toggle client1 to true/false: https://jsfiddle.net/wz7s0tee/5/

Comment: You need to change the html code as well. Please use the html code I provided in the first post. It will work

Comment: I can't change the HTML the way you recommended because this would change the layout for ALL clients. It would make the Login button appear in front of the Forgot Password link for everyone. Any modifications made can only affect the one client requesting these changes, no one else. At best, I can change HTML to look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/wz7s0tee/7/

Comment: That's fine. Just make button tag before anchor tag as I did in the code. And now swap the classes depending upon the client.